# Problems with adding files form git add

Tags: github

I have a problem with Github contributions. If I update the file on GitHub with `git add` Github doesn't show my work in contributions but if I change any file in the browser on Github add my work in contributions. So who have or had this problem???

Answer (score 2):

Have you added, committed, and pushed the change?

The workflow in local repositories is to use

1. `git add <filename>` to stage the file.
2. `git commit -m  "<Your commit message>` (skip -m "message"  to open the configured editor).
3. `git push` to push your changes to the remote repository.

With steps 1 and 2 you have only modified our local copy (clone) of the repository. To add the local changes to Github, you need to push them. So, the last step will show your changes on Github.

Why the Github form is working:

On Github, you change the file in the form and you enter your commit message below the form. No need to push the changes here as you are already working in the remote repository. It's already live when you confirm your commit message.